# Chrome DevTools | Scrolling issues in preview pane when rendering into HTML

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-devtools

**In the Network panel of the Chrome DevTools, with the filter request type set to All/XHR, under the Preview pane scrollbar (both Vertical & Horizontal bar) doesn't rolls**

[image]
In order to overcome the above situations, I have followed these two approaches they are as follows:
Since both the approaches follows the same as, undocking the DevTools into a separate window and then hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> or pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to inspect inside the DevTools — Inspect-in-Inspect (i.e., nested inspects)

### First Approach:

Inspecting the Preview iframe, you'll be able to see `.html-preview-frame` has a `pointer-events` property set to `none`. 
Disabling or setting the `pointer-events` property to `auto` the scrolling function resumes until you refresh the page or switching into another file.

[image]

### Second Approach:

By using a local modified CSS script to override. In the **Sources panel** from the nested inspects, there is a script named ***"network/requestHTMLView.css"***  that appears in the **Sources list**  under the “**No Domain**” section of the **Page tab** and from the **Editor pane** modifying/replacing the CSS script containing previous lines of code with these below lines of code, scrolling function resumes! until & unless without refreshing the page or switching into another file.

```
iframe.html-preview-frame {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 20px;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

[image]

---

But the problem that was faced was each time, if we try to refresh or switch to another file it'll remain persistent.  Is there any workaround to fix this issue permanently either through by defining our own custom CSS file or by defining our own JavaScript functions and then embedding it to HTML file.

Finally, the solution should be such that even though after refreshing or switching to another file scrolling function should work!

Installed Google Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit).

```
Google Chrome:  67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision:       a337fbf3c2ab8ebc6b64b0bfdce73a20e2e2252b-refs/branch-heads/3396@{#790}
OS:             Linux
JavaScript:     V8 6.7.288.46
Flash:          30.0.0.113 /home/nishanth/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/30.0.0.113/libpepflashplayer.so
User Agent:     Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Command Line:   /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Profile Path:   /home/nishanth/.config/google-chrome/Default
```

Awaited for the Official fix through upgrading to a newer release, but couldn't find the fix with this issue and Chrome Canary isn't available for Linux users.

Comment: You can probably author a *custom devtools theme* (google up these terms) or report this on https://crbug.com.

Comment: I've authored a theme, see my answer below. @wOxxOm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone interested. I have Modified a Chrome Dev tool Theme with the above mentioned CSS fix. It's a dark theme, but the same fix can be applied to any other DevTools theme.

Link: [chrome-devtools-zerodarkmatrix-theme](https://github.com/bonlineza/chrome-devtools-zerodarkmatrix-theme)

**UPDATE**
If you clone the repo you can [load it directly](https://superuser.com/a/247654)

**UPDATE #2**
Chrome Browser 68 includes this fix - no more need for a custom DevTools Theme. You can disable the above theme (if you installed the suggested Theme) by following the install instructions  in reverse.

Comment: Good work @SebastianScholle it really works!.  Likewise, as  @wOxxOm said and from the supervisor's suggestion @KayceBasques From the Dark Theme, you have enlightened us from `WontFix` status, as suggested by  paulir...@chromium.org.

Comment: Chromium have patched this issue and they will likely release the fix in a new stable Chrome release in about 10weeks.

Comment: Bug:   [849204](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/122037b2541bf0932fd6fbcb29a98d487525c4ec)  
Status changed to `Fixed`   

In both the `RequestHTMLView` css & js file  
**Removed :** `pointer-events: none;` - *Restores pointer events (including scrolling) to HTML preview.*  
**Added   :** `iframe.setAttribute('tabIndex', -1);` - *Prevents accidentally focusing inputs/links inside the preview iframe when tabbing via keyboard*.  

Finally, we are eagerly waiting for official release @KayceBasques

Answer (score 3):

DevTools technical writer here. Sounds like a bug. Please file an issue at https://crbug.com.

Comment: Copied that from wOxxOm. What will be the turn-around-time to fix this issue? Here I have posted with this link [Scrolling issues in preview pane when rendering into HTML](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=859287)

Comment: The issue was updated with a `WontFix` status. Looks like we may need to go the `Custom Dev Tools Theme` route.

Comment: wow I thought was a feature, but seems to be a bug..., we're looking for solutions or workaround not for confirmations

Comment: Seems it was fixed after all: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/122037b2541bf0932fd6fbcb29a98d487525c4ec

Comment: **68.0.3440.75** (Official Build) version of Google Chrome stable release the scrolling function again resumed. Looks like you have little ground-working to do in the documentation section at https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/devtools. @SebastianScholle

Comment: @Nishanthॐ the correct page link is: https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2018/07/stable-channel-update-for-desktop.html