# Can't scroll XHR preview in Google Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I use Chrome with Dev Tools and I perform an Ajax request, I can't scroll down in the Preview tab if content is HTML.

I can see the scrollbar but I can't click on it or scroll down.

Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Some of my workmates have the same issue.

Is there any way to fix this?

I tried to disable all extensions but it still happens.

Thanks.

Comment: Having exactly this issue, it is like the Preview is stuck in a framed window and is unscrollable.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094360/chrome-devtools-scrolling-issues-in-preview-pane-when-rendering-into-html Solution is simply to upgrade to version 68

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Oli in the question comments, this is fixed when updating to Google Chrome 68.

Thanks.